# How to destory instance of class when finished Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I use MVVM in my project . 
first at all see Edit Action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async virtual Task<ActionResult> Edit(int code)
    {
        var attributeModel = await _attributeService.GetAsync(code);
        EditAttributeViewModel attributeViewModel = mapper.Map(attributeModel, new EditAttributeViewModel());
        return View(attributeViewModel);
    }
```

in ViewModel I count instance like this :

```
 public class EditAttributeViewModel
{
    private static int counter = 0;
    public EditAttributeViewModel()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    }
    ~EditAttributeViewModel()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
    }
}
```

when Finished `Edit` Action and change controller , comeback again to that `Edit` Action and when see `counter` always it increase , While I am moving between pages.I do not want to use too much memory, for do this I `Override` `Dispose` Method in controller like this :

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

    }
```

but It doest chnage and counter always increase .

**How can I Clear Instance when Finshed ActionMethod**

Comment: `counter` is `static`. There is only one instance of it.

Comment: whan I Edit a row 5 times , counter = 5 , while a change controller and againg comeback to edit that row again and counter increas to 6 ...

Comment: Yes, I know - because its `static`!

Comment: ok I know it , I want to know  what time ASP.NET Engine (garbage collector ) destory instance ?

Comment: @UthmanRahimi `static` content gets destroyed when you application gets restarted. Its the only instance for all the requests, consider it as global. Just remove it and you're good to go.

Comment: When you close you app (and there is only one instance of it so its not using any extra memory (just 4 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in C++, you can't free memory on demand. The Dispose pattern is there to release unmanaged resources (file handlers, connections, or pictures that are unmanaged, read: reserved outside of the .Net Memory management as well as anything that uses `IntPtr`).

All you can do is, to set all references to null and call `.Dispose()` on all disposable types in your class, then **wait** until the garbage collection pick them up.

Depending no how your application utilize memory, this may be sooner or later. If your application often instantiates and unreferencing objects this may happen sooner, if your application doesn't it may take longer.

You **shouldn't** depend on that the finalizer (that looks like deconstructor in C++) is called or when. GC calls it, when it's cleaning it up. But only if you haven't suppressed it (which you typically do inside Dispose method).

Answer (score 2):

Because `counter` is marked `static`, it will persist throughout the lifetime of the application (agnostic to specific instance of classes). If this is not the desired result, and you want a fresh instance of `counter` with each instance of the class, remove the `static` keyword.

```
 private int counter = 0;
```

This will create a new instance of `counter` for each instance of `EditAttributeViewModel`.